# How to link count chars in CK editor textarea?

Tags: ckeditor

Ckeditor is magic, but it was programmed to mess with me.

I've linked to the CDN and instantiated a textarea that is given the id cke_quotation. In the original textarea, I had a jquery function that on keyup and focusout, there was a count for characters. Now I want to link this function to the ckeditor quotation, which has the id cke_quotation. It won't work, though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor doesn't work on plain textarea - it's working with contenteditable element instead. If you would like to listen for key events you'd need to listen to, so called, editable.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.quotation;
editor.editable().on( 'keydown', function( evt ){
    console.log( 'keydown', evt );
    // You could call editor.getData() to get current editor
    // contents and then count anything you like.
} );
```

But instead of looking for events like `keydown` you should be more interested in more "input agnostic" event like [`change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) (because change might be caused by different sources, like `paste`, `cut`, drag and drop).

Then again if you're looking for word counting feature for CKE then why bother with creating your own plugin? You could simply use something like [wordcount](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) plugin.

Comment: I'm missing something important here. I'm not experienced in dealing with plugins, so I don't know how to instantiate them. I changed from textarea to paragraph, made it contenteditable="true" and tested to make sure it sends data. But when I paste the code that you provided, it gives me an error:

"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'editor.editable().on')"

Is it the instantiation that is wrong? When you write editable, do you mean that I should use the jQuery plugin that offers that functionality, or that I should replace editable() with something else?

Comment: First off, you don't need to change textarea into `p` with `contenteditable`. Then, yes there are couple of assumptions here. You need to use this code after you called `CKEDITOR.replace` or `CKEDITOR.inline` methods (so that editor is already instantiated). And you need to know the name of your instance, it's taken after id of an element that the editor was created for. Here I assumed "quotation" but if you changed the element then the instance name is different. You can list all the instances by inspecting `CKEDITOR.instances` object.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I had to write it like this: editor.on( 'change', function()... then under function, var chars = editor.getData();--then you do a length on the chars. I wasn't sure what getData, that you mentioned, was doing.

Comment: Addendum: counting characters with getData() seems to fail when you use space or press enter. What happens is this: the first space counts as one character (as it should), then the second spacebar counts as 6 characters; and so goes back and forth. A similar thing happens when one presses Enter. So I'm guessing the solution is to use the plugin, as there is no simple way of counting chars? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: That's probably due to the fact that subsequent spaces needs to be replaced with &nbsp; entity, and you're not decoding it. Counting chars / words in WYSIWYG based on HTML might get tricky in edge cases. Try to check how some open source word counting plugins are implementing it to get a better understanding.

Comment: I just noticed that when I checked the source and was going to add the same observation you made. Cheers.